# Adding a Unique Constraint over multiple columns with violating rows

Tags: postgresql, unique-constraint, alter

We're trying to add a unique constraint to our postgres table in a way that deletes the duplicates rather than throwing an error. The unique constraint spans two columns, and there is no primary key. For example:

```
i_id | term   | date_created
1    | 'mako' | 123456789
1    | 'mako' | 123451234
1    | 'tele' | 213456852
2    | 'rake' | 598521542
```

So, in this example, we would need to remove that second row before we could safely add the unique constraint. Normally we would do a delete command with a select distinct thrown in, but we don't have any distinguishing key for the rows. Specifically, the unique key would be over the columns [i_id, term].

(WTF didn't we have a unique constraint from the start? Go figure.)

I'm thinking a delete statement would be the best, but I can't simply write

```
delete from table where row_id not in (select row_id ... distinct something ... )
```

because there is no primary key for the row. I'd rather avoid a temporary table, if possible. Any suggestions?

EDIT: Sorry. We're using postgres 8.4.

EDIT 2: The solution we're using is:

```
delete from table where ctid not in (
  select 
    distinct on (i_id, term)
    ctid
    from table
    order by i_id, term
);
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: What's your version of PostgreSQL? (This is almost always useful to add.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM the_table
WHERE ctid NOT IN (SELECT min(b.ctid)
                   FROM the_table b
                   GROUP BY b.i_id, b.term)
```

Comment: This is very elegant. But how is `min(ctid)` guaranteed to match the oldest (or newest) row according to `date_created`?

Comment: It doesn't. I don't see that requirement in the question

Comment: Maybe I misinterpreted `So, in this example, we would need to remove that second row ..`. It makes more sense to have a consistent pick for `date_created`.

Comment: Oops - I did overlook that part... ;)

Comment: you're right, we don't need the most recent or least recent entry, just one that works.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your dups do have distinctions in the date_created column, so you could use [windowing](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html) function to capture the values of all but the first row for your duplicate sets, then use that to delete only the extra rows.

```
delete from foo
using 
(select i_id, term, date_created
 from (
  select foo.*
    , row_number() over (partition by i_id, term order by date_created asc) the_rank
  from foo
 ) ranked
 where ranked.the_rank <> 1
) extras
where foo.i_id = extras.i_id and foo.term = extras.term and foo.date_created = extras.date_created;
```

This is substantially similar to Erwin's answer. It differs in selecting the oldest entry to keep instead of the latest, which can be changed by altering the order by to DESC from ASC in the ranked subquery.

Comment: This is basically my answer, just with subqueries instead of CTEs and a more verbose syntax for the WHERE clause ... Only you take the oldest row, not the newest.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter indeed it is, we must have crossed in the answer posting -- I've noticed SO has some substantial latency.  What's SO etiquette on "duplicate answers"?

Comment: I guess the consensus is to delete later duplicate answers. But your answer is not a complete dupe, I would leave it. Also, CTEs need Postgres 8.4 or higher, while subqueries work with older versions. (Well, window functions need 8.4+, anyway.)

Comment: Actually, CTE support is available since pg 8.4.